# How to recalculate css with jQuery window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently trying to recalculate the height of the li during window resize/scrolling inwards or outwards, but for some reason when the page loads it will no longer re-calculate the height and set the ul to it's child height.

This is the code that I wrote to check the height and set the height to it's parent.

```
  var ulHeight = $(".carousel__slider li").outerHeight();
  $( window ).resize(function() {
        $(".carousel__slider > ul").height(ulHeight);
  });
  $(window).trigger('resize');
```

How can I make jQuery resize recalculate the height on window resize? I've created the exact exemple that I'm using on my site now.

https://jsfiddle.net/va5hpL0r/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $( window ).resize(function() {
        ulHeight = $(".carousel__slider li").outerHeight();
        $(".carousel__slider > ul").height(ulHeight);
  });
```

calculate height on resizing 
https://jsfiddle.net/dnL0neux/

Comment: (heavy sigh) I didn't imagine to think the outerHeight should have been inside to recalculate. Appreciate it.